# HTACCESS - Allow access to folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current htaccess.

Site
|.htaccess
|--/folder-1
|--/folder-2

Now my root htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want users to access all files and folders inside folder 1 and folder 2. How that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Several changes: do your domain redirect first (note the subtle changes);

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:folder-1|folder-2)(?:$|/)|public/(?:index\.php)?$).* public/$0 [L]
```

This incorporates the folders you're excluding from rewriting into the main rule, so should be more efficient. It looks ugly since it starts with a negative look-ahead assertion `(?!` and the rest of the groups begin with `(?:` so they are non-capturing.

Do you really need a single domain? If so, it should be checked on all requests. If not, drop the first `RewriteCond` of the second `RewriteRule`.

if your default document is not `index.php`, change it in the negative look-ahead assertion of the second `RewriteRule`.